# Combining for loops

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

How would you combine these loops together..

Is it possible to make the loop use the first tag as category, then access the next tag which would be used for the title?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//get root and current URL
var loc = document.URL;
var root = document.location.hostname;
var path = window.location.pathname;
var dir = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'));

//read in posts from tumblr
if (root != 'www.tumblr.com') {
    var posts = tumblr_api_read.posts;
    for (var i in posts) {
        $('#project-list').append('<li><a href='+posts[i].url+'>'+posts[i].tags[0]+'</a></li>');
    }
} else {
    $('#project-list').append('<li><a href="#">project title</a></li>')
}

if (root != 'www.tumblr.com') {
var posts = tumblr_api_read.posts;
for (var i in posts) {
  $('#installation-list').append('<li><a href='+posts[i].url+'>'+posts[i].tags[1]+'</a></li>');
}
} else {
$('#installation-list').append('<li><a href="#">installation title</a></li>')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can could combine it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //get root and current URL
    var loc = document.URL;
    var root = document.location.hostname;
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var dir = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'));

    //read in posts from tumblr
    if (root != 'www.tumblr.com') {
        var posts = tumblr_api_read.posts;
        for (var i in posts) {
            $('#project-list').append('<li><a href=' + posts[i].url + '>' + posts[i].tags[0] + '</a></li>');

            $('#installation-list').append('<li><a href=' + posts[i].url + '>' + posts[i].tags[1] + '</a></li>');
        }
    } else {
        $('#project-list').append('<li><a href="#">project title</a></li>');

        $('#installation-list').append('<li><a href="#">installation title</a></li>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this

```
if (root != 'www.tumblr.com') {
    var posts = tumblr_api_read.posts;
    for (var i in posts) {
      $('#project-list').append('<li><a href=' + posts[i].url + '>' + 
                                  posts[i].tags[0] + '</a></li>');
      $('#installation-list').append('<li><a href=' + posts[i].url + '>' + 
                                  posts[i].tags[1] + '</a></li>');
    }
} else {
    $('#project-list').append('<li><a href="#">project title</a></li>')
    $('#installation-list').append('<li><a href="#">installation title</a></li>')
}
```